# extjs 5 tree length of undefined

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am converting an ext4 app to 5 and keep getting a ***"length of undefined"*** `error` in the `model.js` file.  My `Tree` matches the examples on the in [Sencha Docs Tree Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/components/trees.html)
Any thoughts to what is causing this.  I am using old charts in the app and it requires compatibility because of some of the chart customization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same issue recently within an application i converted from `ExtJS4` to `ExtJS5`.

When i was initially building the app I had seen to include `compatability : "4.2"` within my `app.json` file in the root folder.

This compatibility option caused the same issue for me with the `treepanel`.  If you have this option enabled and can remove it, it should fix the issue.

Comment: This was exactly my problem.  I removed compatibility and did an app refresh.

Comment: You can probably do sencha app upgrade in the cmd and then do a refesh and it should update this automatically.